# Creating a key value pair based on a condition in a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

Been having a bit of a problem trying to figure out how to include an item in my hash based on a condition.

I've tried using `||=` operators, I've tried ternary syntax too but it seems to always throw a syntax error.

I have a working solution, I just know there has to be a more elegant way to do this.

I have this code in a controller that handles my Amazon API requests and you;re only allowed to sort results if you select a `SearchIndex` other than `All`.

```
if params[:searchindex] = "All"
  parameters= {
      'SearchIndex' => params[:searchIndex],
      'Keywords' => params[:search_term],
      'ResponseGroup' => 'ItemAttributes'
    }
else
  parameters = {
    'SearchIndex' => params[:searchindex],
      'Sort' => 'salesrank' ,
      'Keywords' => params[:search_term],
      'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images"
      }
end

res = req.item_search(query: parameters)
```

It works but its a lot of duplication and I can only see it getting worse

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring working code. It is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ah I was unaware, please close if necessary. Fresh eyes helped, I was searching for a way to insert a new value in a hash based on a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) method to merge unique key value pairs based on condition.

```
parameters= {
  'SearchIndex' => params[:searchIndex],
  'Keywords' => params[:search_term]
}

case params[:searchindex]
when 'All'
  parameters.merge!({ :'ResponseGroup' => 'ItemAttributes' }) 
else
  parameters.merge!({ :'ResponseGroup' => 'ItemAttributes,Images', :'Sort' => 'salesrank' })
end
```

For every other searchindex you would add a `when...` condition and `merge!` the required attributes.

Comment: so you basically set the ones that are universal, and then have a case switch which merges in the ones that change  is the `:'Sort'` proper syntax?

Comment: As an alternative to `merge!` (aka `update`), you could have simply `case params[searchindex]; when 'All'; parameters[:ResponseGroup] = 'ItemAtrributes'; else; parameters[:ResponseGroup] = 'ItemAtrributes,Images'; parameters[:'Sort'] = 'salesrank'; end`. @Rob, I see no problem with that.

Comment: Great thanks for the answers, needed a new set of eyes on it, I didnt think about just creating it with the universal ones and then adding the differences in later on

Comment: @CarySwoveland not sure why you have it as `parameters[:'Sort'] = 'salesrank'` that colon is screwing it up, worked fine with `parameters['Sort'] = 'salesrank'` however

Comment: I just pulled it from @vee's code, but I see now that all of the keys of the key/value pairs you are adding are strings, not symbols, so that should fixed in both `merge!` statements above and in my suggestion. btw, my `params[searchindex]` should be `params[:searchIndex]`.